# How can I exclude the $-1$ case to conclude that $x$ is a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, we define the norm function $f:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {d}] \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ by: $ f(a+b\sqrt d)=|a^2-db^2|$. Suppose that $f(x)=1$, how can I prove that $x$ is a unit?

What I've got: Suppose $x=a+b\sqrt d$ and $f(x)=1$. Then $a^2-db^2=\pm1$. Let $y=a-b\sqrt d$. Then $xy=a^2-db^2=\pm1$. How can I exclude the $-1$ case to conclude that $x$ is a unit?

Also, I'm not sure if the following statement is true: if $f(x)$ is prime in the ring of integers, then $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$? Haven't got a clue for this one...

Comment: $xy=-1$ is fine, too. Then $x\cdot(-y)=1$, hence $x$ is a unit. For the whole statement see [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149886/prove-that-n-gamma-1-if-and-only-if-gamma-is-a-unit-in-the-ring-mat).

Comment: I see... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $xy=-1$, then $x(-y)=1$ so $-y$ is the multiplicative inverse of $x$.

For your second question. First prove that $f$ is multiplicative, i.e., $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. Then suppose $f(x)$ is prime, but $x$ is reducible. Then there exists non-units $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ such that $x=ab$. But then $$f(x)=f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$ and since $f(x)$ is prime, we must have $f(a)=1$ or $f(b)=1$. This implies that $a$ or $b$ is a unit by the first part. This is a contradiction since we assumed $a$ and $b$ to be non-units. Thus $x$ is irreducible.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your answer.