# The units in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta ],\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]=\{a+b\zeta:a,b\in\mathbb Z\} $, and $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=\frac{-1}2+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, ($\zeta^3=1$)

Define the norm $N:\mathbb Z[\zeta]\rightarrow \mathbb Z$ by $N(a+b\zeta)=a^2+b^2-ab$

I need to show that $\alpha$ is a unit iff $N(\alpha)=1$.($\alpha=a+b\zeta$) and finding all the units

I showed $\Rightarrow$, now if $N(\alpha)=1$, then $a^2+b^2-ab=1$, so clearly if $a=b=\pm 1, a=\pm 1\ \& \ b=0, and \ a=0\  \& \ b=\pm 1$

I need another method that is not involving  the calculations of the units. In fact, I need to write the general form of $\alpha^{-1}$, so I can confirm it is a unit.

Comment: For the second question, that $a$ is a unit iff $N(a)=1$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149886/prove-that-n-gamma-1-if-and-only-if-gamma-is-a-unit-in-the-ring-mat).

Comment: So, they form a group . Wonderful, thank you for posting the links