# Difficulty proving $N(a) = 1$ if and only if $x = 1$ or $-1$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that $N(x) = 1$ if and only if $a = 1$ or $-1$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}[-5]$, where $\mathbb{Z}[-5]$ is the set of numbers in the form $a + b\sqrt{-5}$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $N(x) = a^2 + 5b^2$.

Isn't the norm $N(x) = x^2 = 1$, which means $x = 1$ or $-1$, and the proof is simple as that?

Comment: Seems your difficulty is not in **proving the statement** but in **understanding the statement**. E.g. $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not what you describe. It's the set of numbers of the form $a + b\sqrt{-5}$ with $a, b \in \Bbb Z$. And you need to show that, for any $x = a + b\sqrt{-5}$ with $a, b \in \Bbb Z$, if $N(x) = 1$ then $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: @WhatsUp I guess what I'm confused by is that $N(x) = x^2$ no matter what x is equivalent to, so should $N(x) = x^2 = 1$ be enough to prove that $x = \pm 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N(x) = a^2 + 5b^2 = 1$ then $b = 0$, else $N(x) > 1$ since all terms are non-negative and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $a^2 = 1 \Rightarrow a = \pm 1$ and indeed since $b=0$, $x=a=\pm1$.

<strike>**Edit**: are you sure your norm is as stated? Normally it is $a^2-5b^2$, and in that case the question generalizes and there are several ways to prove it; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149886/prove-that-n-gamma-1-if-and-only-if-gamma-is-a-unit-in-the-ring-mat?rq=1).</strike>

**Edit 2:** As pointed out below, this is fine.

Comment: Regarding the edit, no for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ the norm is indeed $a^2+5b^2$. The norm $a^2-5b^2$ is for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Ah good catch, I need better glasses I think.